# Perl: variable in loop uses same memory location, causing overwrite problems

Tags: perl

```
sub read_file {
    open("person_file", "<person_data.txt");
    my $class = shift;
    my @people;
    while (<person_file>) {
        # entries are delimited by a | character
        # format is
        # firstname|lastname|streetaddress|town|state|zipcode
        my $line = $_;
        chomp($line);
        my @broken_line = split(/\|/, $line);
        print Dumper(@broken_line);
        my $curr_person = new Person;
        $curr_person->set_first_name($broken_line[0]);
        $curr_person->set_last_name($broken_line[1]);
        $curr_person->set_street_address($broken_line[2]);
        $curr_person->set_town($broken_line[3]);
        $curr_person->set_state($broken_line[4]);
        $curr_person->set_zip_code($broken_line[5]);
        print $curr_person->get_full_name(), "\n", 
            $curr_person->get_full_address(), "\n";
        push(@people, $curr_person);

    }
    print "\n\n\n";
    foreach my $person (@people) {
        print $person->get_full_name(), "\n", $person->get_full_address(), "\n";
    }
    print Dumper(@people);
    print "\n\n\n";
    close("person_file");
    return \@people;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$VAR1 = 'K';
$VAR2 = 'M';
$VAR3 = '4th St';
$VAR4 = 'New York';
$VAR5 = 'NY';
$VAR6 = '10001';
K M
4th St
New York, NY 10001
$VAR1 = 'C';
$VAR2 = 'G';
$VAR3 = '3 Fifth Ave';
$VAR4 = 'New York';
$VAR5 = 'NY';
$VAR6 = '10003';
C G
3 Fifth Ave
New York, NY 10003



C G
3 Fifth Ave
New York, NY 10003
C G
3 Fifth Ave
New York, NY 10003
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 'Person')}, 'Person' );
$VAR2 = bless( do{\(my $o = 'Person')}, 'Person' );
```

The first chunk of output occurs in the loop when I read the file. The second is in the second loop where I check the array just to see if all of the variables are proper, which they are not.
So the problem I figured out was that $curr_person would not receive a new memory location even if it went out of scope or called as a new Person; and would share the memory location with $people[0] etc. making it so that all of the elements in people would be overwritten by whatever was in $curr_person.

Is there a way I can get $curr_person to get a new memory location each iteration of the loop?

Thanks

Person class:

```
package Person;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $first_name;
my $last_name;
my $street_address;
my $town;
my $state;
my $zip_code;
my $unique_id;

sub new
{
    my $instance = shift;
    bless \$instance, "Person";
}
```

This is my very first non-exercise (5 line) Perl project ever, and I am still trying to understand the syntax of OOP in Perl.

Comment: Your code is fine (well, it could be improved, but it isn't *wrong*). You can get the object ID by `0+$curr_person` unless it is overloaded – but it should be different every time. It seems like there is a bug in the `Person` class. Could you show that code (e.g. the constructor)? It looks like it may be using the error-prone “Inside-out object”-pattern.

Comment: Looks like something weird inside the new subrouting in Person class, like returning always the same instance.

Comment: The `Data::Dumper` output looks like the object is blessed using `bless \$class` and not using `bless $hashref, $class`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you need is already in the comments: the Person constructor must be returning the same instance every time, and consequently every item in the `@people` array is a pointer to that same instance, and when you update one you are updating all.

Show us the code for `Person::new`.

**Later**:

Thanks for the code. Turns out I guessed wrong: it's not  that your constructor is returning the same instance every time. The problem is with your data storage: every different Person instance is using the same set of variables (the `my` declarations under `package Person;`), so as you've already experienced, when you update one `Person`, you've updated them all.

Find a tutorial or a textbook with a worked-out example of a class with get and set methods, and pay special attention to how each instance manages to keep its data (first name, last name, etc.) separate from all the others.

Comment: Edited in. I'm not sure exactly how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

A method gets the invocant as first argument. The invocant is the object when called on an object:

```
$person->foo(); # $_[0] is Person object
```

or the class name (as a plain string) when called on that class:

```
Person->foo();  # $_[0] is "Person" string
```

The usual `new` method looks like this:

```
# Usage: Person->new(first_name => "Fred", last_name => "Flintstone")
sub new {
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  # process arguments
  bless \%args => $class;
}
```

The first argument is the class name. We bless into that class (not neccessarily `Person`!), so that our class can be inherited, and the `new` method reused.

Inside the other methods, we use the fields in the object (which is just a special hashref) to store data – but *not* global or lexical variables!

```
sub first_name {
  my $self = shift;
  if (@_) {  # if there are args
    $self->{first_name} = shift;
  }
  return $self->{first_name};
}
```

et cetera. This is explained in [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) which you should *really* read.

Because writing `new` and accessors is repetitive and boring, people have come up with smart object frameworks that make working with objects more expressive. The most important is the [`Moose` framework](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose). We could then write:

```
package Person;
use Moose;  # this is now a Moose class

# declare attributes with `has`:

has first_name => (
  is => 'rw',  # this is now a read-write attribute
)
...
has street_address => ( is => 'rw');
has town           => ( is => 'rw');
has state          => ( is => 'rw');
has zip_code       => ( is => 'rw');
...

# new is autogenerated!

# a normal method
sub get_full_address {
  my ($self) = @_;
  return sprintf "%s\n%s, %s %s",
    $self->street_address, $self->town, $self->state, $self->zip_code;
}
```